# How to authenticate a person who has facebook but not the facebook app on iOS device?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I am creating an app on iOS and i came across a scenario if a person does not have the facebook app installed but has Facebook. how does the game app handle that.  you can only play the game if and only if you have facebook account?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Single Sign On in Facebook.

So that the facebook will authenticate its user through facebook app if its installed otherwise through the safari.

Here is the [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786819/how-to-implement-single-sign-on-sso-using-facebook-ios-sdk-for-iphone) also [here](http://www.zimbio.com/Mobile+Application+Developments/articles/e5nmrHSqCu3/Facebook+iOS+SDK+Tutorial+iPhone+App+Facebook).

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

If you targeted the older versions (below ios6) use [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/).

If you targeted for newer version (ios 6 and above) use the [native method](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/ios-6/)